# JUnit - How to test the main method that takes a user input and prints a result accordingly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, input, junit, output

I have a calculator that takes input and prints result. For example:
Input to scanner:

```
2+3+4=
```

Prints:

```
9.00
```

I want to test this main method in JUnit. This is how far I came so far (Operator is the class):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MainTester {
    
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream resultByte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final PrintStream result = System.out;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(resultByte));
    }
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        Operator operator = new Operator();
        
        String input = "2+3+4=";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
    
        String[] args = null;       
        System.out.println(operator.main(args));
        assertEquals("9.00", resultByte.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Testing is much easier if you separate responsibilities. E.g. the part that computes the result should not be the same as the one that is reading the input and printing the output. If `Operator` had a method `compute`, that takes a String with the input ("2+3+4") and returns a String with the result ("9.00"). You can then test that this method returns the expected result. Your `main` method would then read the input pass it to `compute` and print the result.

Something along these lines:

```
String result = operator.compute("2+3+4");
assertEquals(result, "9.00");
```

Comment: "How to test main method that takes a user input and prints a result accordingly?" - I don't think this answer addresses how to test the main method.

Comment: The real question is how to test the computation. Testing it by analyzing the console output is rarely the right approach in the first place. If it were really just about the I/O then it would also not be the right approach, because it would intermingle the I/O test with the computation. That's why I suggested to split the responsibilities (I/O, computation).

Comment: "The real question is how to test the computation. " - I misunderstood the original question.  I have deleted my answer which demonstrated how to test the `main` method.  Thanks.